# Twilio how to connect Autopilot to a Studio flow

Tags: twilio

I have set up a demo Twilio studio flow which can process a loan via text or voice. I would now like to put an autopilot in front of it to chat to the user to identify they want a loan and then pass them to my studio flow.

Ideally this would be seemless but I suppose it could pass details from the autopilot to the studio and perform a call back. Is either approach possible?

Answer (score 3):

As of May 23, 2019 Studio has added Autopilot widget support.

Here is a [blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/autopilot-support-chat-studio?utm_campaign=&utm_medium=email&utm_source=drip&utm_content=OTHER_PRODLNCH_2019-MAY-22_Autopilot_Studio_widget_and_Chat_support_announcement_WW_EM_1_3450&utm_term=WW) that has the details of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've had a look around and it doesn't look like there is a dedicated Autopilot Studio widget yet.

I've not spent much time with Autopilot myself yet, but a look over the docs suggests that you can maybe use the [Autopilot Query endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/api/query) from an HTTP request Studio widget. The Query endpoint returns JSON which can be parsed and read by other widgets in Studio.

Let me know if that helps at all.